# Ceiling and Floor of a number for array in descending order (Java)

Tags: java, binary-search, floor, ceil

This is the program I wrote to find ceiling and floor of a Number.

```
public class BinarySearchAlgorithm {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = {10, 9, 8, 7, 4, 3, 2, 1};
        int target = 6;
        System.out.println(ceilingOfNumber(arr, target));
        System.out.println(floorOfNumber(arr, target));
    }
    
    static int ceilingOfNumber(int[] arr, int target) {
        int start = 0;
        int end = arr.length -1;
        boolean isAscending = arr[start] < arr[end];

        while (start <= end) {
            int mid = start + (end - start) / 2;

            if (target == arr[mid]) {
                return mid;
            }

            if (isAscending) {
                if (target > arr[mid]) {
                    start = mid + 1;
                } else {
                    end = mid -1;
                }
            } else {
                if (target > arr[mid]) {
                    end = mid - 1;
                } else {
                    start = mid + 1;
                }
            }
        }

        return start;
    }

    static int floorOfNumber(int[] arr, int target) {
        int start = 0;
        int end = arr.length -1;
        boolean isAscending = arr[start] < arr[end];

        while (start <= end) {
            int mid = start + (end - start) / 2;

            if (target == arr[mid]) {
                return mid;
            }

            if (isAscending) {
                if (target > arr[mid]) {
                    start = mid + 1;
                } else {
                    end = mid -1;
                }
            } else {
                if (target > arr[mid]) {
                    end = mid - 1;
                } else {
                    start = mid + 1;
                }
            }
        }

        return end;
    }
}
```

I am trying to get the index value for the ceiling of a number and floor of a number.

Clearly from the Array -

ceilingOfNumber should return : 3
floorOfNumber should return : 4

but instead,

ceilingOfNumber is returning : 4 
floorOfNumber is returning : 3

I tried to debug it and I also did code-tracing but couldn't find any solution.

Comment: The function is called ceilingOfNumber, buy it has an array as first parameter. Same for ceilingOfNumber. What are those functions even supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

The **problem** with your implemented code is that, you are **always returning start index for celling value and end index for floor value, even when you are considering both Ascending and Descending order array.**

Let's understand the issue. As per the logic, if the target number not present in the actual array, the loop will only terminate when `end < start`. Now, if it's an ascending order array, end index will have lesser value than start index. Because of that, end index for floor and start index for ceiling have no issue. But **for descending order array, `end < start` implies that start index has lesser value than end index. In that case ceiling should be end index and floor should be start index**.

Your can change your logic as - 
Ceiling : `return isAscending ? start : end;` 
Floor   : `return isAscending ? end : start;`